# libcurl won't load contents of URL

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to load the contents of this URL in order to send an SMS;

`https://app2.simpletexting.com/v1/send?token=[api key]&phone=[phone number]&message=Weather%20Alert!`

Using this bit of code implementing libcurl:

```
std::string sendSMS(std::string smsMessage, std::string usrID) {   
    std::string simplePath = "debugOld/libDoc.txt";
    std::string preSmsURL = "https://app2.simpletexting.com/v1/send?token=";

    std::cout << "\n" << getFile(simplePath) << "\n";
    std::string fullSmsURL = preSmsURL + getFile(simplePath) + "&phone=" + usrID + "&message=" + smsMessage;

    std::cout << fullSmsURL;

    //Outputs URL contents into a file
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fd;
    CURLcode res;
    char newFile[FILENAME_MAX] = "debugOld/noSuccess.md";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fd = fopen(newFile, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, fullSmsURL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fd);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fd);
    }
}
```

I've used pretty much this exact code before to save the JSON contents of a URL to a file, although I'm trying something a bit different here.

This URL will actually send an SMS when visited. When using curl in a cli, I have no problem doing this. Although from C++, it doesn't treat anything as a error, just perhaps the actual function to send the sms isn't being actuated in the same way it would had I visited the URL physically.

I've scoured google for some kind of a solution to no avail. Perhaps I'm too novice to curl to know exactly what to search for.

Edit #1: getFile function

```
//Read given file
std::string getFile(std::string path) {
    std::string nLine;
    std::ifstream file_(path);

    if (file_.is_open()) {
        while (getline(file_, nLine)) {
            return nLine;
        }
        file_.close();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "file is not open" << "\n";
        return "Error 0x000001: inaccesable file location";
    }
    return "Unknown error in function 'getFile()'"; //This should never happen
}
```

Comment: Have you checked for any rogue characters (such as newlines) returned by `getFile`?  Perhaps show the implementation of that function.

Comment: I've edited the post with the getFile function. There's nothing I can see that would be causing it within getFile(), although I don't trust myself at this point. Thank you!

Comment: Try outputting the length of the string it returns, and check that this matches the number of characters you expect.

Comment: Just looking at your call to CURL (which I have no experience in using), I can't help but notice that it accepts arbitrary arguments in a C-style interface, so if you are passing `fullSmsUrl` to it (which is a `std::string`), things could go really wrong.  A `std::string` will not implicitly convert itself to a `const char*`.  Try this: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, fullSmsURL.c_str());`

Comment: That seems to be correct as well. When reading the file it gets 32 chars, which is equivalent to the string length. Just in case my counting is wrong, the string is (similar to): 1jb1d0c0632d40e6hc758b06b5c5f9af

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right! It was simply a step I glossed over. In every other use of curl I changed the concatenated string to a char*, though I forgot this time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, fullSmsURL);
```

`CURLOPT_URL` expects a `char*` pointer to null-terminated C string, not a `std::string` object.  You need to use this instead:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, fullSmsURL.c_str());
```

Also, you are not performing any error checking on the return values of `getFile()`, `fopen()`, or `curl_easy_perform()` at all.  So, your code could be failing in any one of those places and you would never know it.

Comment: I'm pretty new to curl, and relatively new to c++ in general. I'm looking up some resources on how to error check on those functions. Do you have any recommendations for resources?